# Difference between {% include '' %} and {{ include('') }} in Twig

Tags: symfony, include, twig

It's possible to include a file in two different ways:

```
{% include 'fic.html.twig' %} 
{{ include('fic.html.twig') }}
```

What is the difference between the two methods?

Source:

- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html
- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tags are less flexible than functions, for example:

1. If you want to store contents of a file in a variable if you want to repeat it twice:

   {% set content = include('test.twig') %}

Instead of:

```
{% set content %}
{% include 'test.twig' %}
{% endset %}
```

2. If you want to add filters:

   {{ include('alert.twig') | upper }}

Its tag equivalent:

```
{% set temp %}
{% include 'alert.twig' %}
{% endset %}
{{ temp | upper }}
```

You see, `{{ include }}` instead of `{% include %}` will not change the world, but remove some complexity when you need to do tricky stuffs using Twig.

Also, according to the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html), it is recommended to use `{{ include() }}` to fit with best practices:

```
{{ }} is used to print the result of an expression evaluation;
{% %} is used to execute statements.
```

Answer (score 3):

From Twig's [changelog](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/v1.12.0/CHANGELOG):

```
* 1.12.0-RC1 (2012-12-29)

 * added an include function (does the same as the include tag but in a more flexible way)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the same functionality, but while `{% include '' %}` is a tag, the `{{ include('') }}` is a function. Maybe if you want to overwrite the function it can be easier than a tag.

Answer (score 0):

From Symfony 2.8 (LTS)  [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/templating.html#including-templates)

> **2.3** The include() function is available since Symfony 2.3. Prior, the {% include %} tag was used.